# Как настроить доступ в php.ini для exim из пакета Vesta через SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, exim

Я на облачный сервер установил Vesta, по умолчанию там был PHP 5, я отдельно установил PHP 7.3 и появилась проблема, не работает функция `mail()`, вернее она работает, но письма не доходят. Мне кажется это из-за того, что в файле конфигурации `php.ini` стоит путь

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Я никак не пойму, как в этой переменной прописать путь к `exim`?

Comment: Там скорее всего симлинк. `ls -ld /usr/sbin/sendmail` куда ведет?

Comment: в /etc/alternatives/mta

Comment: `ls -la /etc/alternatives/mta` куда-то дальше ведет? Вообще в конце симлинк будет указывать на одну из почтовых программ. Можно еще просто запустить `/usr/sbin/sendmail` - выведет `Exim is a Mail Transfer Agent ...` или что-то еще. Если с консоли `echo "test" | mail -s "test mail" ваш-ящик@mail.ru` - письма на ящик приходят?

Comment: /usr/sbin/sendmail - выводит Exim is a Mail Transfer Agent, а письма не приходят.

Comment: А когда я из админки пытаюсь письмо отправить - ошибка SMTP ошибка (550): Невозможно установить отправителя "admin@boxpvm.ru" (Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3))

Comment: Думаю теперь надо искать проблему в настройках exim

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config`